# Exception unwrapping key: bad padding: Decryption error

Tags: java, encryption, jks

I am trying to decrypt a file "test.txt.p7b", which encrypted using a cert inside a JKS.

I received this error while debugging my code. Appreciate if someone can explain why is this error about. Is my key got problem or my code got problem (mostly, I believe so) .Many thanks

Error message as below,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException: exception unwrapping key: bad padding: Decryption error
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JceKeyTransRecipient.extractSecretKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient.getRecipientOperator(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.KeyTransRecipientInformation.getRecipientOperator(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.RecipientInformation.getContentStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.RecipientInformation.getContent(Unknown Source)
    at TestingB.decryptData(TestingB.java:299)
    at TestingB.main(TestingB.java:161)
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorException: bad padding: Decryption error
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JceAsymmetricKeyUnwrapper.generateUnwrappedKey(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2121)
    ... 8 more
```

And here is my Decryption code.

```
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(_keyStorePath);
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    keystore.load(fIn, _password);
    PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey("def","123456".toCharArray());
    fIn.close();


    File file = new File("C:\\1_Eclipse\\1_CS\\Encrypted\\test.txt.p7b");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] encryptedAndSignedByte = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    fileInputStream.read(encryptedAndSignedByte);
    fileInputStream.close();


    X509Certificate cert9 = (X509Certificate) keystore.getCertificate("abc");
    KeyTransRecipientId recId = new JceKeyTransRecipientId(cert9.getIssuerX500Principal(), cert9.getSerialNumber());

    CMSEnvelopedData enveloped = new CMSEnvelopedData(encryptedAndSignedByte);
    RecipientInformationStore recipients = enveloped.getRecipientInfos();
    RecipientInformation recipient = recipients.get(recId);
    JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient ter = new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient(key);
    ter.setContentProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    System.out.println("content : " + recipient.getContent(ter));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here I cannot see what goes wrong, but the error happens during decryption of the symmetric key by the RSA private key.

CMS is a container format. It contains of methods to handle or envelop the data. If you have an enveloping container then the data in it is not directly encrypted with the RSA public key. Instead it is encrypted with a random symmetric key (often called a data key or even session key). This symmetric key is then encrypted with the public key.

RSA encryption first pads the data, then performs modular exponentiation with the public exponent. Decryption consists of modular exponentiation with the private exponent and unpadding. Now the modular exponentiation will always succeed whatever the value of the data or exponent. So if the data or key is invalid then a padding exception is the only indication.

As the data in the container is likely valid - you would expect a decoding error if it wasn't - it is much more likely that the private key doesn't match the public key. It doesn't rule out implementation mistakes of the CMS library, but I would consider that relatively unlikely if the CMS library has been tested well.

So I would suspect your key value rather than your code - it is of course possible to have a mistake in the code that reads or writes your key as well.

All said, I would definitely fix the stream handling in your code first. Just creating a `encryptedAndSignedByte` buffer and calling `read` once is extremely naive, it may not return all data.

Answer (score -1):

I have amend the code, but same problem occur. I believe the encryption part shouldn't be any problem.

Decryption Code:

```
public static void decrypt(final InputStream is, OutputStream os, Key key, String providerName) throws Exception  {
        final InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, bufferSize);
        final OutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os, bufferSize);
        final Iterator  it = new CMSEnvelopedDataParser(bis).getRecipientInfos().getRecipients().iterator();
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            final RecipientInformation recipient = (RecipientInformation)it.next();
            JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient ter = new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient((PrivateKey) key);
            final CMSTypedStream recData = recipient.getContentStream(ter);
            final InputStream ris = recData.getContentStream();
            fromInToOut(ris, bos);
        }
        os.close();
    }
```

In the Main class

```
new File("C:\\1_Eclipse\\1_CS\\Encrypted\\test_result.txt");
        FileOutputStream E_fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\1_Eclipse\\1_CS\\Encrypted\\test_result.txt"); 
        FileInputStream E_fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\1_Eclipse\\1_CS\\Encrypted\\test.txt.p7b"); 

        decrypt(E_fileInputStream,E_fileOuputStream,key,"BC");
```

I believe the error was caused by this part of my decryption.

```
 final RecipientInformation recipient = (RecipientInformation)it.next();
            JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient ter = new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient((PrivateKey) key);
            final CMSTypedStream recData = recipient.getContentStream(ter);
```

Comment: You know, I completely missed this as it was posted as an answer. Don't create answers as follow-up on questions. Either create a new answer or amend your current one.

Comment: **Future readers beware!**: I don't think this is even an answer. CSSC posted this answer at 7:28 AM but later left a comment for @MaartenBodewes answer at 8:18 AM, saying: "I am able to decrypt the file now. :) Is the key issue." His root cause (and mine?) was that he was using the wrong decryption key. I'm still seeing the `exception unwrapping key: bad padding: Decryption error` even with this code. So even though the presence of this answer would indicate the OP solved the issue with this code, I don't think that was the case.